# alternative to JSONRepresentation in AFNetworking

Tags: ios

I am using SBJSON and Serialiazation in my current application. Now I am replacing NSURLConnection with AFNetworking2.0. I have read that Serialization is possible using AFNetworking. Please Suggest What is the alternative to JSONRepresentation in AFNetworking?

Thanks

Comment: do you want alternatives for JSON parsing or example for non-json data?

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking use [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to parse a JSON and create a Foundation representation underhood. Apple greatly improved the performance of `NSJSONSerialization`. When using iOS 6 and up, it is one of the fastest libraries. You can see it in the docs:

`Warning: JSON parsing will use the built-in NSJSONSerialization class.`:http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFJSONRequestOperation.html
or just in source code.

This makes working with JSON data in `AFNetworking` pretty straightforward.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:someRequest];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

After this you are ready to work:

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
 NSDictionary* response = responseObject;
 NSLog(@"Here is parsed Json data: %@", response);
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
 NSLog(@"Error");
}];
 [operation start];
```

P.S. I advise you strongly to use default `AFNetworking` tools for working with JSON because it will save a significant amount of time and only if you have some very, very specific requirements of performance only then to seek out some faster libs and integrate them with `AFNetworking`. But faster here is not the only criteria. One lib can be a blazingly fast on small pieces of data and be very slow on large chunks.

Comment: Objection: NSJSONSerialization isn't the fastest implementation to parse a JSON and create a Foundation representation. Other third party libs may be up to three times faster ;)   But nonetheless, NSJSONSerialization is fast enough in 99% of use cases!  ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Ok. Thank you. I was too absolute). I've edited my answer.